# Switch off xcode overwrite mode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

Today I start my xcode and found amazing thing: fat karet in editor. I didn't know how to fix it and press some shortcuts after what iOS object browser show me only MacOS controls. I was very dissapointed and decided to set default settings:

$defaults delete com.apple.Xcode 
$rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode

but: Domain (com.apple.Xcode) not found

I can remove xcode, but I think it doesn't solve the problem. 
Anybody know how to fix this(overwrite caret and object browser), or set up default settings, or remove xcode completely?

Google is silent.

**UPD**
It's seems I found solution of first problem. So:
"xcode insert mode" setting up by **XVim nasty plug-in**, just **uninstall** it by deleting folder $HOME/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/XVim.xcplugin in muCommander (Disk Order haven't found it);

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what a "fat karet" is, but can you change it in the Xcode preferences menu?

Comment: it's called "overwrite function": mode, when typing over old text, like dos mode. The preferences doesn't seems useful.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode4 moved some things around, and I suspect you're trying to delete where the settings were for Xcode3. To reset on 4, type:

> rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist

I can confirm that file exists for my Xcode4, although I must admit I didn't actually try it out for you.